# isomorphic subgroups of the additive group of rational numbers

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $H$ and $K$ two subgroups of the additive group of rational numbers $(
\mathbb{Q},+,-,0)$.
Show that if there are positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $mH \subset K$   and  $nK \subset H$  then  $H\cong K$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ is uniquely determined by the prime powers it contains.